# How disable show folder in desktop ubuntu?

Tags: .desktop, desktop-icons

This used to be possible in gnome-tweaks. But now there is no such function

Try command `pcmanfm --desktop-off`, not help

Try disable `show-desktop-icons` in `dconf editor`

Try `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false` not help

USED UBUNTU 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure desktop icons with the "Extensions" tool. Install it from Ubuntu Software, or with the terminal `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs`.

If you do not want any icons at all on the desktop, you can disable the build-in Gnome Shell extension "Desktop Icons NG (DING)". You can disable specific icons or change other options with the button "Settings".

[image]

Comment: Thanks you! But if i disable DING, i not can select an area on desktop
How i can delete future show folder, and at the same time leave the selection function

Answer (score 1):

If you want desktop icons to not show on your desktop, copy this into the terminal:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng -y
```

Done, and you can always re-enable if you want:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng -y
```